# Products created programatically not visible before saving them manually

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We are using a integration module to sync products between Odoo and Prestashop. Most products works out of the box but some products are not working before going in the products and saving them.

I have tried rebuilding Indexes and emptying caches but it does not help. Only thing that "activates" the products is the manual save.

Is there something else I could do?

[You do not have the right to this product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJD3Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually caused by missing category access to customer group (unless you have some third party modules restricting access to products).

I would definitely check that products have a correct **id_default_category** set in both **ps_product** and **ps_product_shop** table when they are created.

Check also the associations between the category and the **id_customer_group** where you are getting the "restriction" warning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry for my delay, been sick. I will check this. Is there any way i can trigger rebuilding/activation for this?

Comment: If "saving" affected products is going to fix them, you can build a simple PHP script that perform a $product->update() operation on involved IDs

Comment: The issue is that we dont manually want to fix them, then updating all nightly could be a solution. 

Do you happend to have an example of a script that would just run each product and update them?